# Which layer protocol is OpenWire

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Which layer protocol is OpenWire? AMQP and Stomp are application layer protocols but not sure about OpenWire. Also, is OpenWire the default protocol used by ActiveMQ for communicating between JMS clients? I looked into the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

OpenWire is the default protocol for ActiveMQ Brokers which is used on the wire between the ActiveMQ JMS client and between networked ActiveMQ brokers.  While the broker does support MQTT, STOMP and AMQP the internals map the messages for those protocols into OpenWire typed objects for storage in the ActiveMQ data store which means that for best performance you should use the ActiveMQ JMS client.

For better cross broker compatibility you could use an AMQP v1.0 JMS client like Qpid JMS but the performance would be a bit lower than the OpenWire based JMS client.

Answer (score 0):

Openwire is built ontop of TCP and it includes data compression and character encoding, so Level 6 of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), I would think.